# No space left on device despite there is a lot of space/inodes/filefd remaining

Tags: linux, filesystems, disk, kubernetes

I'm running EKS worker nodes with EC2 on AWS. There are some nodes saying "No space left on device"; all the pods in those nodes can't create new files. All nodes have only 1 volume (/).

I ssh-ed into one of those nodes and tried:

- Result of `df -h`:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.9G  2.3M  1.9G   1% /run
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p1  100G   55G   46G  55% /
tmpfs           370M     0  370M   0% /run/user/1000
```

- Results of `df -i`:

```
Filesystem       Inodes  IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
devtmpfs         470571    319   470252    1% /dev
tmpfs            472895      1   472894    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs            472895   1004   471891    1% /run
tmpfs            472895     16   472879    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p1 52427760 617280 51810480    2% /
tmpfs            472895      1   472894    1% /run/user/1000
```

- Results of `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max` is 376057
- Results of `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr` is `4992    0       376057`
- Create a new file (`touch new_file`) using non-root user -> failed
- Create a new file using root user -> failed
- Append text to an existing file (`echo "something" >> existing_file`) -> success
- Delete a file and then create a new file immediately (`rm -f existing_file && touch new_file`) -> success

Do any one know why?

Additional information:

- The filesystem is xfs
- Content of `/etc/fstab`

```
UUID=<uuid>     /           xfs    defaults,noatime  1   1
```

- The OS is Amazon Linux 2
- Kubernetes version 1.21
- The `quota -v` command returns nothing

Comment: how about the space in the ec2 instance?

Comment: You can see in the result of `df -h` command I posted above. The total space is 100GB

Comment: hmmm, so the next thing to check would be audit logs (maybe some SELinux permissions have changed? Or something similar.), look for whether there's a a cgroups2 controller that limits the space used by all containers, or maybe classical quotas on that filesystem.

Comment: I don't think there is something to do with the permissions, because I can create a new file if I delete an existing file.
It's not related to the cgroup either, because I ssh-ed with root user, and the error remain the same.
The quotas feature is not enabled too (command `quota -v` return nothing)

Comment: It's like it hit some limits else where

Comment: I agree, the SSH login is a good test, but just to be doubly sure: you can be as much of a root user as you want, if the SSH process spawned is under the same cgroups2 group as the containers! I'd check you're in the default controller, and not subject to some other slice.

Comment: How should I check it? Can you give me some tutorial links? Thanks